# Regex to replace spam links in Wordpress

Tags: regex, code-injection, spam

I am dealing with old hacked sites in Wordpress where there are injection spam links on images. 
I have access to the database and would like to remove links that look like this:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/ansaid-retail-cost">.</a>
```

Now text varies inside the `<href>` it might be for cialas or any product, but the rest doesn't vary. I want to remove the entire LINK, so the result is a single space.

I don't know regex, so I would appreciate the help. I've tried online generators but they don't seem to be working.

Comment: `<a>` is an anchor tag, not an `<img>` tag. Did you mean `<img>`?

Comment: I would suggest using an HTML parser instead of regex to manipulate HTML.

Comment: The html link is attached to an image caption in the database.  However, finding that type of string in the database is what I need to replace by removing it entirely. If I find and replace just the <a style="text-decoration:none" href="  portion it will leave a lot of empty tags or erase things I don't want it to.

Comment: What regex engine/programming language do you use? Also, please add full examples of what you want to match and what you want the output/replacement to be.

Comment: I would be using PHPMYSQL to match patterns in the database with a query

Comment: This is an example of the text: <a style="text-decoration:none" href="/scandinavian-shop-ansaid">.</a>    where  /scandinavian-shop-ansaid   is the text that varies.   The SQL query in the database will not take the entire string because there are too many characters that need to be escaped.  So <a style="text-decoration:none" href=".+?">\.</a>  will not work.